# Show that a real number x is the supremum of a set A

Tags: real-analysis

Let A be a set of real numbers. Show that a real number *x* is the supremum of *A* if and only if *a* $\leq$ *x* for all *a* $\in$ *A* and for every positive number $\varepsilon$ there in an element *a'* $\in$ *A* such that *x* - $\varepsilon$ $\lt$ *a'*

Comment: What is your definition of supremum that you are using for this problem?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and explain what's giving you trouble? For example: Do you know the definition of supremum?

Comment: To explain other comments: what you are asked to prove is one of possible definitions of the supremum (in fact, one of the most common definitions that are used in Calculus), so you need to provide your definition of the supremum.

Comment: I'm referring to the set A as a set of real numbers that is bounded above and nonempty. If x is the least of all the upper bounds, then x would be the the supremum (or the least  upper bound of A)

Comment: What have you tried doing? If you write out the least upper bound definition of supremum in symbols, that should give a few ideas for methods of attack.

Comment: @AngelaCrowley: Your definition says it all. If $x = \sup A$, then $x$ is least upper bound of $A$ and hence 1) $x$ is an upper bound so that $a \leq x$ for all $a \in A$ and 2) $x$ is least upper bound so that any number less than $x$ is not an upper bound. Now $x - \epsilon < x$ and hence it is not an upper bound of $A$ and hence it must be exceeded by at least one member (say $a'$) of $A$. Thus $x - \epsilon < a'$.

Comment: @AngelaCrowley: The formal / symbolic meaning of your definition of "supremum as least upper bound" is mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $c$ is not an upper bound for a set, what does that tell you about the relationship between $c$ and at least one member of the set? Furthermore, if $x$ is a least upper bound for a set, what does that tell you about the relationship between $x$ and all the numbers $c$ which aren't upper bounds at all?